# How to convert asarray's output back to normal array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some code which has used NumPy's asarray and therefore the array looks like this:

```
[[392 200]
 [461 194]
 [392 200]
 [161 202]]
```

I want to convert it back to normal array with commas. I expect it to look like this:

```
[[392, 200],
 [461, 194],
 [392, 200],
 [161, 202]]
```

What's the way out?

Comment: It is a normal array for all practical purposes; just the representation is different.

Comment: Anything that resembles what I have shown. Thanks. @MateenUlhaq

Comment: check this out for one dimension and multi dimensions array conversion in to an array.
https://www.journaldev.com/32797/python-convert-numpy-array-to-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do that, have a look at the snippet below:

```
import numpy as np

np_array = np.asarray([[392, 200], [461, 194], [392, 200], [161, 202]])
python_list = np_array.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing actual data structures with their displays.

If I copy-n-paste your 'normal array with commas':

```
In [593]: alist = [[392, 200], 
     ...:  [461, 194], 
     ...:  [392, 200], 
     ...:  [161, 202]]
```

I get a nested list, which displays as:

```
In [594]: alist                                                                                
Out[594]: [[392, 200], [461, 194], [392, 200], [161, 202]]
```

That's comma separated, but not broken into neat lines.

If I make a `numpy` array from that:

```
In [595]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                                
In [596]: arr                                                                                  
Out[596]: 
array([[392, 200],
       [461, 194],
       [392, 200],
       [161, 202]])
```

The `repr` display of the array includes the commas, but the `str` display omits them:

```
In [597]: print(arr)                                                                           
[[392 200]
 [461 194]
 [392 200]
 [161 202]]
```

That's the same array, same data structure, but with different display strings.

We can get a `list` from that with:

```
In [599]: arr.tolist()                                                                         
Out[599]: [[392, 200], [461, 194], [392, 200], [161, 202]]
```

But the differences between `list` and `ndarray` are much bigger than the comma-or-not display.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to convert to list, you can try [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> np.asarray(x)
array([[1, 2, 3],      # <------ repr
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> print(np.asarray(x))
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
>>> s = repr(np.asarray(x))
>>> print(s.translate(
                      str.maketrans({' ': '', '\n': '\n ', ',': ', '}))
                     .strip('array(/)')
          )
[[1, 2, 3], 
 [4, 5, 6]]
```

Or, much simply:

```
>>> print(str(np.asarray(x)).replace(' ',', ').replace('\n, ',',\n '))
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6]]
```